# Image with buttons below the image in overflow

Tags: html, css

I am trying to locate the buttons right below the image in overflow. I made some progress with overflow and with image, but I am struggling in putting buttons in the right location.

So as you see from [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SalvadorDali/ZchEY/), my ok and back buttons are messed up. I want them to be right below the image (even if you resize the image or have image of different size) with one button on the right side of the image, another one on the left. Something like this:

[image]

Currently they are below the image, but everything else is wrong.

**HTML**

```
<div class="overflow">
    <img  class="img" src="http://ts4.mm.bing.net/th?id=HN.608050962838388827&pid=15.1">
    <div class="button1">back</div>
    <div class="button2">ok</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overflow {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
.img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    bottom:5%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width:90%;
    max-height:90%;
    margin:auto;
}

.button1{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    bottom:5%;
    left: 25%;
}

.button2{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    bottom:5%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

Sorry for not checking a question for a few day. Did not have time to check your suggestions. One more time sorry.

Comment: The fact that you are using `width` and `height` in `percentages` is going to impact the location of the buttons on browser resize

Comment: @imbondbaby if you have any other solution, I will be happy to accept it. I am just trying to make it the way I know, and it looks like I am doing it wrong.

Comment: So can I provide you with a solution with fixed width for the image?

Comment: @Salvador Dali Lost interest in this, did you?

Comment: @ralph.m sorry for long reply. Thank you for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fixed `width` on the image and wrap them around a container.

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="outter">
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="container">
            <img class="img" src="http://ts4.mm.bing.net/th?id=HN.608050962838388827&pid=15.1" />
            <div style="clear:both;">
                <div class="button1">back</div>
                <div class="button2">ok</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#outter {
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
#middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#container {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
}
#container img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
}
.button1 {
    display:inline-block;
}
.button2 {
    margin-left:75%;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Wrapped the image and text around two `div` and used the `table` and `table-cell` method to center them vertically and horizontally.

Change `margin-left` in `.button2` to move the text further.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fwmfL/16/)**

Tested on Firefox, Safari and Chrome and IE9

More info **[here](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.html)** for vertical alignment.

Comment: Even with a fixed width the image not in the center. If you resize the window, you can see that it is not in the center.

Comment: Sorry for all these waiting time. You solution works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZchEY/9/) is what you actually want

In order for things to work properly, you need to first position your buttons relative to the image. I do this by using a `<table>` which some may frown upon, but it gets the job done. A lot of the CSS can go because the table takes care of positioning. The only caveat of this solution is that your table **must** have a fixed `width` and `height` (they have to be specified, but you can of course change them through javascript) in order for you to be able to position it at the center of the page.

The HTML:

```
<div class="overflow">
    <table>
        <tr >
            <td colspan="2">
                <img class="img" src="http://ts4.mm.bing.net/th?id=HN.608050962838388827&pid=15.1" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div class="button2">ok</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="button1">back</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.overflow {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
.img {
    max-width:90%;
    max-height:90%;
}
.button1 {
    color: white;
}
.button2 {
    color: white;
}
table td{
    text-align: center; 
    width: 50%;
}

table{
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    left: calc(50% - 500px/2);
    top: calc(50% - 300px/2);
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

the important parts to remember are `table-layout: fixed` which is what allows us to specify the width of the cells, thus we can make them equal in size and get proper positioning. Also, the `left` and `top` properties are set based on your `width` and `height`, so if you change the width and height you have to specify those as well (since you can't reference CSS properties through `calc()`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how much `position: fixed` is integral to this, but here's a nice solution without it: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/liAJj

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);}
.overflow {display: table; margin: 5% auto; text-align: justify; max-width: 90%;}
.overflow:after {content: ""; width: 100%; display: inline-block;}
.overflow img {display: block; margin-bottom: 10px; width: 100%;}
.button1, .button2 {display: inline-block; width: 50%; color: white;}
.button2 {text-align: right;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="overflow">
    <img  class="img" src="http://ts4.mm.bing.net/th?id=HN.608050962838388827&pid=15.1">
    <div class="button1">back</div>
    <div class="button2">ok</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ZchEY/2/) work?

All I did was change this:

```
.button2{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    bottom:5%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

to this:

```
.button2{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    bottom:5%;
    right: 25%;
}
```

to match the other button.

It seems to flex properly, so I don't see what other problems it has.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work. If you resize your fiddle (make it too narrow), you can see that buttons become too low below the image.

Answer (score 0):

here it is, I hope that's what you want

http://jsfiddle.net/ZchEY/3/

Edited codes:

```
.button1{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    bottom:5%;
    right:8%;
}

.button2{
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    bottom:5%;
    left: 8%;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work. If you resize your fiddle (make it too narrow), you can see that buttons become too low below the image.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML Code:

```
<div class="overflow">
    <div id="img"><img src="http://ts4.mm.bing.net/th?id=HN.608050962838388827&pid=15.1"/></div>
    <div id="buttons">
        <div class="item-1">Item 1</div>
        <div class="item-2">Item 2</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
.overflow {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
}
#img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width:90%;
    max-height:90%;
    text-align: center;
}

#buttons {
    max-width:70%;
    max-height:90%;
    margin: 20px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#buttons .item-1 {
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

#buttons .item-2 {
    color: white;
    width: 50%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but as you see an image is not at the center (vertically). Also if you make the screen size too wide the buttons are outside of the image frame.

Answer (score 0):

With some relative positioning to the image, it appears to be what you want. The problem was that your buttons were not related to the img in any way.

Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/ZchEY/7/

HTML

```
<div class="overflow">
    <img class="img" src="http://ts4.mm.bing.net/th?id=HN.608050962838388827&pid=15.1">
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="button1">back</div>
        <div class="button2">ok</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.overflow {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 5% 0 0 5%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .8);
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.img {
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
    bottom:5%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width:90%;
    max-height:90%;
    margin:auto;
}
.buttons {
    padding: 0;
    max-width:90%;
    max-height:90%;
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
.button1 {
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    top: 15%;
    left: 25%;
}
.button2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15%;
    right: 25%;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the image is not in the center.